# Android image scaling Identical to the background image in a constraint layout

Tags: android, android-drawable, image-resizing, android-constraintlayout

In my App I have one map image and image views around it containing map pieces.In any device screen the map pieces should be equal in size to its respective part in the map image.map image is also included in an Image view within the constraint layout.

[image]

How do I make the images around the map image identical/equal size to the ones in the main image. I created the images set using the "Batch Drawable Import" plugin.When I put the images to the drawable-xxhdpi drawable-xhdpi drawable-hdpi drawable-ldpi folders and they show bigger or smaller pieces when running on devices. 
Those Image pieces will be dragged and dropped to the map view which finally creates a map.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parentcl"
    tools:context=".Act2_1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/x2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView35"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView35"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView33"
        android:layout_width="163dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="368dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView35"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/x1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Above is the test code I am trying.BG image size is 2048px X 1496px and the red box size within it is 400px X 300px.Image piece in outer image view is 400px X 300px. I want the outer image size to be identical to the size of the image within the background image. What is the best solution to achieve the above requirement. I tried placing images inside all the drawable folder within the app but did not succeed. Then I added a large scale images only inside drawable and drawable-nodpi-v4 folder which also did not give a good result.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [Ask] and take the [Tour].

Comment: replace android:background with app:srcCompat and android:layout_width and layout_height should "wrap_content" for both images and use the android:scaleType="centerInside" hope this may help you

Comment: Thank you for your respond Saleem.But that didnt work. What I need is set one image as the background for the entire app and place the small images/ image views on top of it. Their sizes should be equal/identical to the boxes in the bg image. When a user drag a small piece and drop on a box in the bg image for example a pop up will say correct matching.